# Intelij, Spring - Multi module project does not detect any dependencies when using classpath of parent module

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, multi-module

I have a multi-module project. For simplicity, lets say there is a parent pom, and one child pom. I have all my dependencies in `<DependencyManagement>` in the parent pom, and then all of them in the child pom as well. Building the project with maven gives no issues. When running the project, while editing the configuration of the project and setting `Use Classpath of module`: child module, works fine. But when setting the `Use Classpath of module`: to parent module (that was the default), intelij gives errors for every dependency. For every dependency it says that package does not exist.

> Error:(21, 27) java: package com.squareup.okhttp does not exist

even though I have okhttp in the dependencies, I use okhhtp and it works when using classpath of module : child. And i can even see that intelij detects  the okhttp library because I can use CTRL+leftClick to navigate to the library, but when clicking run, I still get the error. Why is this happening, this error is given for every single dependency I have. If project structure or pom details are required, please comment and I will provide as much info as I can. Thank you!

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Comment: Actually yes. Turns out it was just an error with the project iml file. I found that out when i created the project from scratch. Should i delete the question?

Comment: If you feel the solution is tricky and might help others, please answer it here or else you may remove it.